# How to populate email alert with data from multiple objects from a flow?

Tags: flow, email-alert

I have a request to send an email alert, that needs to use data from multiple objects.
Lets say account and opportunity.

[image]

While creating the flow, the only record ID that is sent to the email object, is the record id (AccountId).

[image]

The email alert is sent, but the opportunity id (data fields) are empty.

Is it possible to fill these data from the flow? or do I need an alternate approach here?

Comment: You're going to need to start with the OppId. You automatically have the AccountId from that. How else are you going to know which Opp to reference?

Answer (score 0):

You need VF email template to do this required information can be found

[Create a VF template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_creating.htm)

[Use in Automation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_templates_vf_automation.htm&type=5)

[Email alert action](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_wfalerts.htm&type=5)